# Singleton DataStore on Background Thread

Tags: objective-c, singleton, nsmanagedobjectcontext, background-thread

I have created a singleton class that accesses a datastore and returns an object representing a Core Data entity. This is fine in the normal thread but I am concerned about accessing this singleton method from another class running on a background thread as the background thread will be running with its own copy of the Managed Object Context.

When trying to call the singleton from the background thread do I need to create a fresh instance of the singleton and pass in the background thread's copy of the managed object context or can I safely access the singleton method and allow that to use the shared managed object context that it retrieves internally from the app delegate please?

Comment: "fresh instance of the singleton" How is this supposed to happen?

Comment: Instanciating the singleton through the init event, it gives you a non-singleton copy

Comment: Then what is the point of having a singleton? If you are going to just create your own whenever you want - what is the point of having a singleton in the first place?

Comment: The idea is to have a singleton access method to simplify data access when accessing from the main thread. I would like to continue that access method in a background thread, but if it is not possible you can instanciate it and set the managed object context in the instance you create to prevent thread conflicts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your data manager class make all the relevant Core Data calls with `performBlock:` or `performBlock:andWait:`

That way the calls will always be made in a thread safe manner.

Personally, however, I usually write my data manager so that It is called on the main thread, and it takes care of making any further calls on whatever thread makes sense.

Comment: If you perform it on the main thread don't you get UI blocking?

Comment: Not if the data manager then makes the actual calls on a background thread. My point is that you have a data-manager object. It should be up to that object to perform it's operations on background on foreground threads as is most efficient.

Comment: I will be honest. I had never considered that approach. I currently start the background thread from the view controller and call the data manager from that. I thank you for your advice, it will take me a while to digest this idea and assess it so I will mark your answer as the correct answer and go away and think about this. Thank you .

Comment: Here are some slides from a talk by Marcus Zarra which describe an implementation of a non-singleton data manager http://www.iosdevuk.com/storage/talks2013/MarcusZarraMVC-N.pdf